# Mutable column from mixin does not track mutation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-social-auth

While trying to diagnose an issue I had with `social-app-flask-sqlalchemy`, I found a somewhat unintuitive behavior with `sqlalchemy` where I'm not sure if it's expected behavior or a bug.

Consider the following snippet:

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, PickleType
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __abstract__ = True

class B(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    my_data = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(PickleType))

class C(A, B):
    pass

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
db_session = session_factory()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

assert B.my_data.type.__class__ is PickleType

c_instance = C(my_data={'foo': 'bar'})
db_session.add(c_instance)
db_session.commit()
loaded_instance = db_session.query(C).first()
loaded_instance.my_data.update(baz=1)

assert loaded_instance.my_data['baz'] == 1

assert loaded_instance in db_session.dirty
```

This runs without issues. Now if we *change the superclass of `B` to `object`*, the last assertion errors out. Up until there, everything works fine though.

It turns out that by not having `B` subclass the `declarative_base` directly, the type of `my_data` is no longer enforced to be `MutableDict`, but whatever type we give when instantiating an object (a `dict` in this case). Obviously, this also means that changes to `my_data` are no longer tracked. However, `my_data` still uses `PickleType` as its data type, so the effect is not immediately visible.

I originally stumbled upon this when changes to `extra_data` in `social-app-flask-sqlalchemy` were not written to the DB. `social-app-flask-sqlalchemy` uses an ORM that is similar to the one shown above—the `SQLAlchemyUserMixin` class which holds the `extra_data` column is not subclassing `declarative_base`, but its subclass `UserSocialAuth` does via `_AppSession`.

Now I'm not sure where to report it as an issue, with `sqlalchemy` or `social-app-flask-sqlalchemy`. Any thoughts?

Comment: As to passing the blame, [I believe `social-storage-sqlalchemy` should be fixed](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-storage-sqlalchemy/blob/master/social_sqlalchemy/storage.py#L90), if not badly named model. They have some other interesting patterns as well, such as a [commit-flush](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-storage-sqlalchemy/blob/master/social_sqlalchemy/storage.py#L64), which should be redundant as a [commit first flushes anyway](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit) – unless that's some odd corner case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should [declare complex mixin columns such as yours using the `declared_attr` decorator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#mixing-in-columns). Simple column declarations will be copied from the mixin:

> To accomplish this, the declarative extension creates a **copy** of each `Column` object encountered on a class that is detected as a mixin.

and apparently this does not play well with [mutation tracking](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.mutable). The documentation is perhaps a bit vague on what constructs should use the decorator.

> This copy mechanism is limited to simple columns that have no foreign keys, as a `ForeignKey` itself contains references to columns which can’t be properly recreated at this level. For columns that have foreign keys, **as well as for the variety of mapper-level constructs that require destination-explicit context**, the `declared_attr` decorator is provided so that patterns common to many classes can be defined as callables

Emphasis added, though I might've misunderstood what "destination-explicit context" means in this context. So do this:

```
class B(object):
    ...
    @declared_attr
    def my_data(cls):
        return Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(PickleType))
```

instead, if `B` is to be a mixin class. An example of both the failing simple declaration and `declared_attr`:

```
In [2]: from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict

In [3]: class MixinA:
   ...:     extra = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(PickleType))
   ...:

In [4]: from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

In [5]: class MixinB:
   ...:     @declared_attr
   ...:     def extra(cls):
   ...:         return Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(PickleType))
   ...:

In [6]: class A(MixinA, Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'a'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   ...:

In [7]: class B(MixinB, Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'b'
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   ...:

In [8]: metadata.create_all()
```

and in action:

```
In [9]: a = A(extra={})

In [10]: b = B(extra={})

In [11]: session.add(a)

In [12]: session.add(b)

In [13]: session.commit()

In [14]: session.query(A.extra).first()
Out[14]: ({})

In [15]: session.query(B.extra).first()
Out[15]: ({})

In [16]: b.extra['b'] = 1

In [17]: session.commit()

In [18]: session.query(B.extra).first()
Out[18]: ({'b': 1})

In [19]: a.extra['a'] = 1

In [20]: session.commit()

In [21]: session.query(A.extra).first()
Out[21]: ({})

In [22]: b.extra['bb'] = 2

In [23]: assert b in session.dirty
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks a lot! One follow-up question, when I use `@ declared_attr` in class B, I get a *SAWarning: Unmanaged access of declarative attribute my_data from non-mapped class B*. Do you also get this warning?

Comment: That warning means that you're accessing the attribute directly from the mixin class, instead of a declarative model class that has the mixin. In light of the example above, `MixinB.extra` would raise that exception, because `MixinB` is just a simple class, not a mapped/managed model class. Here's example output: https://paste.ofcode.org/6YenqspiMNs5vH4wfLhDye. The idea behind a mixin is that you use it to contain common behaviour, but you must create real model classes to actually implement that behaviour.

Comment: If you have not read ["Mixin and Custom Base Classes"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html), you should. It explains many mixin patterns.